# RazorJS - Could not load type 'System.Web.Razor.Parser.MarkupParser'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, razor-2, razorengine

When I try to use `@Html.RazorJSInline()` function I get

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Razor.Parser.MarkupParser'

When I try to use `@Html.RazorJSInclude()` RazorJs is generating path to JS file but then I get the same error when trying to open the file with browser.

---

### edit

I think it is caused by that the RazorJS was designed for Razor 1...

Does anybody find out some nice workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Got here a bit late, but I hit a similar problem when trying to call RazorEngine's `Razor.Parse()`. I also got this message:

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Razor.Parser.MarkupParser'

I was at the time using RazorEngine version 3.0.8. [This issue](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/57) was apparently resolved in a later version of RazorEngine (3.1.0)
So upgrading the package to this version fixed it for me.
I used the following command in the NuGet Package Manager Console to upgrade to the fixed version:

```
PM> Update-Package RazorEngine -Version 3.1.0
```

At the moment, RazorEngine is already a bunch of versions further (I think currently 3.7.2) but upgrading all the way to this version wasn't really an option for us, as this would've required quite a bit of refactoring in existing code. If this isn't an issue for you, you could always try the latest version.